# IONIC-I cannot convert 'image to base64'

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, screen

The photo I took using the application camera appears as a black screen. I looked at the other questions and tried some of the answers, but I can't translate the picture to base64. Could you help?

You can see the entire code from the link.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/4FwYdk5fvD/

```
  takePicture(sourceType: PictureSourceType)
  {
    var options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imagePath => {
      if (this.plt.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY)
      {
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
          .then(filePath => {
            let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
            this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
          });
      }
      else
      {
        var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i sorta had the same issue. I also wanted the name (not the path though), and i also wanted a base 64... so what i did what this:

```
takePicture(sourceType: PictureSourceType) {
var options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 80,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true,
    destinationType: 1,
    targetWidth: 1240,
    targetHeight: 768,
};
this.camera.getPicture(options)
.then((imageData) => {
  this.imgService.convertFilePathToBlob(imageData).subscribe(blob => {
    this.image = blob;
  });

   let correctPath = imageData; // or subStr the parts you want
   let currentName = this.image[1]; // grab the name
   let currentImage = this.image[0]; // the image itself as base64


}).catch((err) => {
  console.warn("takePicture Error: " + err);
});}
```

and the convert function... remember to import File, FileEntry from '@ionic-native/file/ngx'

```
convertFilePathToBlob(filePath:string) {
 return from(this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath)).pipe(
  mergeMap((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
          fileEntry.file(file => {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onloadend = () => {
                  const imgBlob = new Blob([reader.result], { type: file.type });
                  observer.next([imgBlob, file.name]); // the name can be grabbed now
                  observer.complete();
              };
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          }, error => {
              observer.error(error);
          });
      });
  }));}
```

This works in my case, but i find it insane i had to do all this, and it took some debugging and googling... i hope it helps you in some way... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got these
`npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@ionic-native\file\ngx" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-07T20_06_16_706Z-debug.log`

Comment: I added your code, in my app, i can took a photo, but the photo doesnt seem

Comment: Sounds like a plugin/platform/node_modules issue. Whenever odd errors happen for me, i remove platforms and node_modules and run npm install and ionic cordova platform add ios/android maybe also try remove and add the plugin (File) again.

Comment: I have try your code but `convertFilePathToBlob` return me an empty blob, i get only filename. And i think that correctPath, currentName & currentImage should be inside the subscribe.

Comment: Actually, I ran my code in a real device without did not any change. There was no problem. It is only the code does not running on the virtual device.